# Заявки приходят в спам

Tags: php, email, sendmail

При отправке формы с сайта письма приходят в спам. Вот PHP код

```php
<?php   
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$email_address = trim($_POST['email']);
$phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
$message = trim($_POST['message']);

// Create the email and send the message 'recepient'
$to = "тут почта на mail.ru";
$email_subject = "Заявка с сайта:  $name";
$headers = "тут почта на mail.ru";
$email_body = "Новая заявка!\n\n"."\nИмя и Фамилия: $name\n\nТелефон: $phone\n \n $message";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers,"Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"");        
?>
```

Comment: 1 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=ru 2 https://help.mail.ru/mail-help/rules/info 3 https://yandex.ru/support/mail-new/web/spam/honest-mailers.html

Comment: DKIM, SPF, DMARC, TLS - это всё должно быть настроено на вашем почтовом сервере

Comment: @andreymal хост на Windows. Это как-то влияет?